# Sublime & Xdebug - page freezes on refresh but no output on Sublime windows

Tags: docker, sublimetext3, sublimetext, xdebug

I've been trying to setup Xdebug on Sublime Text for my projects following basically the steps on this link

https://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-xdebug-sublime-text-3/

My projects are running on docker, so this is my setup

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && a2enmod rewrite
COPY docker/config/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

The xdebug.ini file

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=my local ip address here
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=sublime.xdebug
```

The sublime-project

```
{
    "folders": [{
        "name": "Name of the app",
        "path": ".",
        "follow_symlinks": true,
    }],
    "settings": {
        "xdebug": {
            "path_mapping": {
                "/absolute/path/to/server": "/absolute/path/local"
            },
            "url": "http://localhost",
            "port": 9001,
            "ide_key": "sublime.xdebug",
            "close_on_stop" : true
        }
    }
}
```

I have also set in the browser extension (both Firefox & Chrome) the sublime.xdebug, but when I start debugging and refresh the page I can see the page "freezing" on loading, but I get no output on the console windows of Sublime. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

This is the xdebug.log I get when I refresh the page

```
[18] Log opened at 2019-05-16 17:54:12
[18] I: Connecting to configured address/port: my-ip-address:9001.
[18] I: Connected to client. :-)
[18] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.4" protocol_version="1.0" appid="18" idekey="docker"><engine version="2.7.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2019 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
[18]
[18] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>
[18]
[18] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_children -v 32
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>
[18]
[18] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_data -v 1024
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>
[18]
[18] <- feature_set -i 4 -n max_depth -v 1
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>
[18]
[18] <- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file%3A///var/www/html/public/index.php -n 21
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="180001"></response>
[18]
[18] <- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t exception -x "Fatal error"
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="180002"></response>
[18]
[18] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t exception -x "Catchable fatal error"
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="180003"></response>
[18]
[18] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t exception -x "Warning"
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="180004"></response>
[18]
[18] <- breakpoint_set -i 9 -t exception -x "Parse error"
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="180005"></response>
[18]
[18] <- breakpoint_set -i 10 -t exception -x "Notice"
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="10" id="180006"></response>
[18]
[18] <- breakpoint_set -i 11 -t exception -x "Strict standards"
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="11" id="180007"></response>
[18]
[18] <- breakpoint_set -i 12 -t exception -x "Deprecated"
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="12" id="180008"></response>
[18]
[18] <- breakpoint_set -i 13 -t exception -x "Xdebug"
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="13" id="180009"></response>
[18]
[18] <- breakpoint_set -i 14 -t exception -x "Unknown error"
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="14" id="180010"></response>
[18]
[18] <- run -i 15
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="15" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/html/public/index.php" lineno="21"></xdebug:message></response>
[18]
[18] <- context_get -i 16 -c 1
[18] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="16" context="1">
```

The last line (i.e. `<response xmlns=urn:debugger_protocol_v1"`) is is a massive xml file which as far as I can see contains all my ENV variables and ends with this

```
[18] Log closed at 2019-05-16 17:54:28
[18]
[20] Log opened at 2019-05-16 18:00:07
[20] I: Connecting to configured address/port: my-ip-address:9001.
[20] W: Creating socket for 'my-ip-address:9001', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[20] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[20] Log closed at 2019-05-16 18:00:07
```

Comment: Collect and check Xdebug log: it should provide clues to what is happening (where it tries to connect to etc): `xdebug.remote_log`

Comment: @LazyOne I have updated my post

Comment: First part (till `[20]`) looks OK to me: file in question is `/var/www/html/public/index.php`, breakpoint is set at line 21 + exception breakpoints (which may not work as Xdebug may not be in a right mode; unsure on this) + _"massive xml file"_ is all current PHP variables. That 2nd part (`[20]`) .. looks like 2nd debug session and it unable to continue .. which could be because first session is still in progress (or something like this). Maybe it's a call to a missing `favicon.ico` file, which gets handled by the same index.php file.... not sure.

Comment: Since I'm not using Sublime Text myself, I do not know how it works with Xdebug (can it handle more than 1 debug session at a time?); Maybe ST just closes debug as soon as first session is over so it does not want to accept 2nd one etc. Or maybe it's Docker related issue. Sorry, no better ideas ATM.